# Confusion about onclick function

Tags: javascript

Beginner JS here, hope anyone could explain this to me.

1) Why does this not work:

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
allSpans.onclick = function() {
 alert('hoo'); 
};
```

2) or if I have all the innerHTML from spans in an array and I try this:

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var arrayNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
  var operator = allSpans[i].innerHTML; 
}
arrayNumbers.onclick = function() {
 alert('hoo'); 
};
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName doesn't return one element but a list.

Answer (score 2):

1. `onclick` is a property of *HTMLElementNode* objects. `getElementsByTagName` returns a *NodeList*. Assigning a property to a *NodeList* doesn't assign it to every member of that list.
2. Exactly the same, except you are dealing with an *Array* instead of a *NodeList*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through the returned list

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for ( var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i += 1 ) {
    allSpans[i].onclick = function (event) {
         alert('hoo'); 
    };
}
```

Comment: Alright, I get it, but in JSlint the error: Don't make functions within a loop. occurs? Is this something to look at or does it not matter?

Comment: @Marek: It doesn't matter in your example, but it's something you have to aware of. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you have to add this on each node instead of the nodeList, which is what you're getting when you call `document.getElementsByTagName`. What you're looking for is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++){
  allSpans[i].onClick = function(){
    alert('hoo');
  };
}
```

You have a similar issue in the second question, except it doesn't appear as if you're actually adding anything to the `arrayNumbers` array, so even if you looped through that, you wouldn't get the expect events on click.